# Getting char pointer from function

Tags: c, arduino

Forgive me if its too basic but i get crashes and it seems i dont really understand things.

I have a global variable :

```
char *incomingData="";
```

then i have this function which gets some data from some hardware :

```
void readWifDataAsSever(char* reqData)
{
          char data[100]={0};
          //...
          if (len > 0) 
           {

                  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
                       data[i]=(char)buffer[i];

               ParseGetRequest( data ); //some other manipulation
                   reqData=data;
            }
          else
            reqData="";

}
```

Then i am trying to call that function from another place ,give it the global variable, and get the new data from the function :

```
readWifDataAsSever(incomingData);  //incoming data is the global i just show
//check length of incomgin data
```

Well obviously , not only that i am doing things wrong, i dont really get the things with the pointers.

I know that `data's` life is only inside the function.

I am trying to understand why is this wrong and how should you really do it.
thanks.

Comment: I'm not getting you. If you know that data variable scope is local, what is the question?

Comment: How you really should do it ? :)

Comment: I wonder why don't you get an error message on `char *incomingData="";`...

Comment: @Alex.S thanks, ,maybe because its hardware environment . This is why i came here to understand the whole thing from basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not allowed, because the moment the `readWifDataAsSever` exits the `data` becomes invalid. Accessing it through any pointers that may be still pointing to it is undefined behavior.

However, your program is not even doing that: since you pass `reqData` pointer by value, any assignments to it have no effect in the caller, i.e.

```
reqData=data;
```

does *not* change what the caller of your function sees.

In order to fix the problem you need to do one of two things:

- Pass a valid *buffer* to the function, along with its length, or
- Make a dynamic allocation inside the function, and have the caller free the result.

Since you are working on an embedded system with limited resources, the first approach is the most appropriate in your situation:

```
size_t readWifDataAsSever(char* reqData, size_t maxLen) {
    if (len > 0)  {
        size_t activeLength = len < maxLen ? len : maxLen;
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < activeLength ; i++) {
            reqData[i]=(char)buffer[i];
        }
        return activeLength;
    } else {
        reqData[0] = '\0';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is tagged Arduino, the only sensible solution is to pass a valid buffer. Dynamic allocation should never be used on simple embedded system.

Comment: @Lundin You are right, I didn't see the tag. When resources are so limited, dynamic allocation is the first one to be dropped. Thank you!

Comment: thanks a lot ! well i cant load the data inside the for loop because after the for loop i have some other manipulation on data. see my edit please.

Comment: @Curnelious You can do the same manipulation in place using the buffer passed into your function, i.e. `ParseGetRequest(reqData);`

Comment: thanks again. Wow do i really need all of this just to get some value out of function in C ?? maybe i am already used to object oriented..

Comment: @Curnelious I agree! Programming in C feels so much like coding in assembly language after trying C++!

Comment: @Curnelious As they say, "C combines the power and performance of assembly language with the flexibility and ease-of-use of assembly language."